# How does it possible to use enumeration values in JanusGraph?

Tags: gremlin, janusgraph

How is it possible to define some enumeration type (like java-enumeration) in janus-graph DB by gremlin query?

It seems that something like enum can be define by `List` typed property:

`enumProperty = mgmt.makePropertyKey('State').dataType(String).cardinality(Cardinality.LIST).make()`

Is there another way?

Ideally, I would like to be able to refer to these enumerated values (as in Java SomeEnum.ENUM_VALUE_1) when creating/updating the vertices/edges by gremlin queries.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can create a LIST or SET cardinality property using pure Gremlin if you are working with a graph that does not have an explicit schema API. Here are a few examples

```
g.addV('test').property('p1','one').property('p1','two')
==>v[55985]

g.V(55985).valueMap()
==>[p1:[one,two]]

gremlin> g.V(55985).property(list,'p1','three')
==>v[55985]

gremlin> g.V(55985).valueMap()
==>[p1:[one,two,three]]
```

Hope this helps,

I have fairly detailed coverage of this concept in the book/tutorial which you can read for free here http://kelvinlawrence.net/book/Gremlin-Graph-Guide.pdf or here http://kelvinlawrence.net/book/Gremlin-Graph-Guide.html

Cheers
Kelvin

Comment: Thanks for the book reference! 
According to the section "4.7.10. Adding properties to other properties (meta properties)" I consider to use metaproperty  - e.g. `stateValues` with LIST carnality for property (e.g. `hasState`) of enumerated type.
Do you think this is an acceptable solution?